# How To Append Extent reports 4.1.0 using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-extent-report

I want to Achieve the below scenario

(Say if I have 2 testcases, when I run the First test it generate a Html Report
and now when I run the second Testcase if it fails it should not be appended To the existing Report but when we fix and rerun it should be appended to the Existing report if it passes).

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I figured out that Append feature is not available for version 4.1.0 in .Net, But will be available in version 5.0 as per the author of Extent Reports anshooarora.

version 5 and above are already available for Java